# Adobe Flex XML Encoding

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Having issues encoding my XML for european characters. Example, where there should be:
ã instead I am seeing: Ã£.

The file is being written through the following method:

```
var fs : FileStream = new FileStream();
var targetFile : File = new File(paramURL);
fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);

fs.writeUTFBytes(updatedXML);

fs.close();
```

I have additional code checking for regions selected by the user, appending:

```
updatedDynXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"iso-8859-1\"?>
```

Or

```
updatedDynXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
```

To the XML String before it is written.

Are there any steps I might be missing in creating an XML that supports these international characters?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - Turns out my method of encoding above was infact doing so correctly - and my external application was re-encoding it incorrectly. Closed, but leaving this here for people who are trying to write XML correctly.